# I have difficulty using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i am trying to do my website's link style like this:

```
^admin/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$  index.php?usertype=admin&url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

if there is no admin i want to usertype=user like this:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?usertype=user&url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

maybe there is good an option but i am trying to learn.
i did it, usertype=admin is working normal but usertype=user not working well :D
[here is link](http://tepegoz.epizy.com/admin/web-siteler) this link is working but when i go this [link](http://tepegoz.epizy.com/) it redirect me to 404 not found page and i did it for a moment but the css / js files didn't come so I got it back

Comment: Why do you want to do this in htaccess? This would be much better suited in a controller, a middelware, or even just in your script.

Comment: like 
^(.*?)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA] ?? i don't know how should i do this

Comment: In the script that ends up using `userType` you could do something like `$userType = isset($_GET['userType']) ? $_GET['userType'] : 'user';`

Comment: thank you for your ideas i got it